# Creating a new dataframe with only 1 row per value

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to fill a pandas dataframe (Dataframe 2) with rows from an original dataframe (Dataframe 1). I've created a mock Dataframe 1 below:

```
Ref Number  Name
1           Alpha
2           Alpha
3           Alpha
4           Alpha
5           Beta
6           Beta
7           Beta
8           Charlie
```

I want to delete rows where the value Name has occurred in previous rows. I.e. Dataframe 2 should look like

```
Ref Number  Name
1           Alpha
5           Beta
8           Charlie
```

The Ref Number doesn't matter in this instance. In my working files, I'm planning on adding a column to specify something, and then to refer to that when applying some function.

How would I go about this with Pandas? I've got a CSV with ~5000 rows and I want to limit that to a 2nd dataframe with ~1000.

Comment: What do you mean by "the Ref Number doesn't matter"? Is it redundant? In that case why bother with a tabular format? You just want the set of values, which is `set(df["Name"])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with specifying column `Name` for find duplicates:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates('Name')
print (df)
   Ref Number     Name
0           1    Alpha
4           5     Beta
7           8  Charlie
```

Comment: Thanks! Added it !

Comment: We should be able to find a decent [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=df.drop_duplicates)..